# Is there a source that the Messiah can die and return?

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, messiah, resurrection-of-the-dead

Is there a source in Judaism that indicates that Moshiach (Ben David, not Ben Yosef) will die before having fulfilled his role and then return to posthumously achieve it?

Comment: Wait... die without having redeemed the nation then return to fulfill his role?

Comment: @jake Yes, I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: You mean like in Christianity?

Comment: @SethJ I don't think so, but I have only a very superficial knowledge of christianity. I don't mean die to atone for anyone's sins though.

Comment: @SethJ, Christianity believes that the "savior" not only died and has yet to return, but also that he is is some way "part of" God, or at least godly in some sense. That is not implied by this question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses why your edit?

Comment: @msh210, this sounds like a hashkafa question to me, but feel free to overrule.

Comment: Sanhedrin 98a says if Klal Yisroel is deserving Moshiach will come WITH the clouds of heaven, if they are not deserving he will come riding a donkey. The Tannaim and Rishonim who endured some of the worst persecution by the Christians were not bothered by the notion of a Torah Observant Jew fit to be Moshiach returning again yet our generation who lives in almost no persecution will equate the notion to their man g-d yashkeh.

Comment: Note Rambam writes (Melachim 11 3) that when Bar Kochba was killed, it was definitively established that he was not Mashiach. That seems to preclude the possibility of resurrection.

Comment: It seems this question is the main machloket between David Berger and Chabad.

Comment: who is "David Berger" ?

Comment: Rambam writes that the messiah will die. I don't know anyone besides Paul who says he will return after death. That is a Christian idea, not Jewish.

Comment: @Ze'evmissesMonica "this question is the main machloket between David Berger and Chabad." No, it is the main machloket between Chabad before 1994 and Chabad after 1994. David Berger is just a proxy for "everyone".

Comment: @KapinKrunch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Berger_(historian)

Answer (score 3):

In The [Yerushalmi Brachos daf 17:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1102.htm) (see Eicha Rabbah 1:51 as well ) says : The Rabbanan said if Mashiach is from the living David is his name, if he is from the dead, David is his name,

R' Tanchuma says the reason is based off Tehillim 18:51.

Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said his name is Tzemach.

Rabbi Yuden ben R' Aivo said his name is Menachem.

However, it is brought that Mashiach(kingship) will come from Shlomo Hamelech([Rambam Mitzvah Lo Taseh 362](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1155518/jewish/page.htm) ) ,and it is also brought down that the soul of Mashiach will be  from that of Moshe( [Ohr Hachaim 49:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14147&st=&pgnum=171) ) Meaning the soul of Mashiach is from great people not necessarily that these people are Resurrected.

Comment: Why the down vote (I don't care for the points just like to know why my answer is not sufficient) ?

Comment: Not my vote, but presumably the issues with this source would parallel those in the comments to the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple sources say that the Moshiach will be hidden for some time, and come back and be revealed

Rashi on Daniel 12:12 says

> Moshiach will be revealed, concealed, and then revealed again

Also Midrash Rabba Bamidbar 11:3

> Rabbi Berachia in the name of Rabbi Levi said: Just like the first redeemer, Moshe, revealed himself to the Jews and then concealed himself, similarly the final redeemer will reveal himself and then conceal himself, and then return and reveal himself again

Comment: Conceal doesn't mean "die" though. At least, not necessarily. In particular considering that Moshe didn't die in his concealment.

Comment: Well it will seems like he will die when really he didnt, like Moshe Rabeinu

Comment: so you're saying that the Mashiach won't die? It will only seem as though he did?

Comment: Yes, just like when Bnei Yisrael thought that Moshe had bevadai died, even though he didn’t. Same with moshiach

Comment: But the question is about a figure *actually dying* and then coming back as Mashiach.

Comment: Well that’s a good question then, since the Moshaich’s “death” (before he comes back) will be some sort of an illusion

Answer (score 2):

[Sanhedrin 98b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=98b&format=pdf):

> אמר רב אי מן חייא הוא כגון רבינו הקדוש אי מן מתיא הוא כגון דניאל איש חמודות
>
> *Said Rav: If he [Mashiach] is from the living, he is like our great teacher [R' Yehuda HaNasi]. **If he is from the dead**, he is like Daniel, greatly beloved man [i.e. the Biblical Daniel].*

Comment: Can you explain that passage, it is a bit cryptic.

Comment: @bcholbeisineeman, I think it was meant to be cryptic. I did once see a nice explanation of it, but I will have to look around for it.

Comment: Couldn't it just mean "If you look for a model among the living...or among the dead..."?

Comment: @SethJ, Fair enough. And seems [Ben Ish Chai](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20116&st=&pgnum=84) seems to think along the lines of what you suggested.

Comment: @SethJ, Add to that [Maharal](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14192&st=&pgnum=225). As well as, of course, Rashi in *lishna acharina*.

Comment: @SethJ, re "Couldn't it just mean...", yes, but the question was whether there's a source, and this _g'mara_ is such (according to the first explanation in _Rashi_ here) AFAICT.

Comment: @msh210, True. But note that according to the first *lashon* of Rashi, it seems that if Mashiach will be from the dead, he actually *will* be Daniel.

Comment: jake, I was going to respond to @msh210, Aderaba, that Lishna Rishona in Rashi is written in past tense ([actually past perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_perfect)) _for the Daniel mention_, implying that if Mashiaḥ had been someone who has since passed away, it _would have been_ Daniel.

Comment: @SethJ, good point, so it's not a good source for this question after all.

Comment: @msh210 Although I'm not sure what exactly the Nafka Mina is between Lishna Rishona and L"A. Maybe to say, "If we had merited redemption, Mashiaḥ would have been Daniel, but we didn't, so he wasn't," as opposed to, "Here's an example of Mashiaḥ," I guess?

Comment: the text reads "k'gon" so I don't think it is reasonable to read it as if it is pointing to Daniel as an actual potential returning messianic figure. Rashi in the first explanation says "v'im hayah me'otan" if it had been from those, then the nominee would be Daniel based on his life experiences. The L"A then adds that each is a paradigm but not an example.

Comment: @Dan, _Rashi_ explicitly discounts the "_k'gon_".

Comment: I don't see that he discounts it, only that his use of two answers hinges on its power as inclusive or exclusive. the first gives the actual potential candidates in their time and the second gives the notion of the paradigmatic role for anyone at any time.

Comment: jake, if your basis is Rashi's first explanation of the gemara (despite SethJ's on-the-mark remarks), shouldn't that text be included in the answer? From the discussion above it is clear that this gemara alone is not sufficient as an answer; even Rashi's first understanding had to _lav davka_ a word out of it, so just citing pshat is seemingly insufficient.

Comment: While you're at it you should point out whose translation it is, especially because the phrasing of the translation is particularly significant here.

Comment: The the most recent Lubavitcher Rebbe ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15959&st=&pgnum=218) footnote 6) understands that this gemara must be referring to the soul of Daniel (or some other dead person) which would be in the Mashiach, not that the dead person himself would arise and be Mashiach.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think you are parsing that footnote correctly. The statement in the last paragraph of the footnote refers back to Rav Pappa's question, not the sources in the previous paragraph. Otherwise the footnote does nothing to address the statment in the body that the "simple" meaning is that "Dovid" refers to Moshiach instead of saying "it must refer" to Moshiach (which is the question introduced in the first paragraph of the footnote).

Comment: @Yishai Reading the *sicha* in context, it appears that the explanation of R' Pappa's question is provided in the body later on, and that the last paragraph in the footnote is there to reconcile the second paragraph with the first one, along the lines of DoubleAA's comment. Thus the footnote ultimately supports the position assumed in the body, that David HaMelech will not literally be resurrected in his own body as the *mashiach* (contrary to one of the possibilities suggested by a simplistic reading of the *Y'rushalmi*).

Comment: @Fred, read the third paragraph as a standalone footnote without the first two paragraphs. Fits perfectly - which is my point. More importantly, the answer that it will be the Neshama doesn't seem to address the יפה ענף and the Radak brought in the second paragraph as they speak about תחיית המתים, thus it is hard to see how it addresses just the Yirushalmi. There is more to say (like the use of the word לכאורה which generally - but not always - invokes an ultimately rejected idea), but nothing else is dispositive, I don't think.

Answer (score -1):

Rambam writes that the Messiah will die. I don't know anyone besides Paul who says he will return after death. That is a Christian idea, not Jewish.

Answer (score -1):

The question asked was, "*will* die before having fulfilled his role and then return" [italics mine]. Some here have brought Midrashim that *might perhaps* be understood that it is *possible* for that to happen. I would guess that the right answer is that there is no source at all that predicts that it *will* happen, since the notion [espoused by Christians, of course] was treated with universal scorn by all Jews, Chabad and non-Chabad alike, until recently.
The only reason the question is being asked is that so many people from Chabad got pulled into this position by events. For something like that one needs [Bayesian Inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference): What did one estimate as the likelihood of this happening, *before* events made it the only possibility that fits with one's prior assumptions, the only chance to still be right. If that likelihood was ridiculously small (as anyone from Chabad would have said emphatically in 1993), what one is supposed to do is re-evaluate one's priors, not follow them into further results that would earlier have been rejected as crazy.

Answer (score -2):

not exactly as you are asking. There is no source that someone proclaimed to be moshiach vadai can die and then come back to complete their mission as moshiach. There is a notion that moshiach may be someone who has passed away. The gemara quoted from Sanhedrin 98b does show someone who has passed away may be resurrected in order to be moshiach. This should explain to you the distinction between someone being moshaich, dying, and then coming back (not valid)versus someone who has passed away being the moshiach (valid).